# Java..Array required, but string found

Tags: java, arrays

I'm attempting to create a new array of indexes from str2 parameter, but getting this error: "Array required, but string found." 
I'm learning Java, and only comfortable writing in Javascript. Could someone explain what this error message means?

```
public class Scramblies {

    public static boolean scramble(String str1, String str2) {
       String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
       int[] inOfStr2Nums = new int[str2.length()];


       for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++){
          inOfStr2Nums[i] = alphabet.indexOf(str2[i]);     
        }
         System.out.println(inOfStr2Nums);

    }

}
```

Comment: You can't access a character in a string using `str2[i]`. That operation only works for an array.

Comment: Also, you'll want `println(Arrays.toString(inOfStr2Nums)) `

Comment: str[i] is not a valid way to get the character out of string. You can convert your string to character array, and then iterate over it:



     public static boolean scramble(String str1, String str2) {
  String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  int[] inOfStr2Nums = new int[str2.length()];

  char[] str2Array = str2.toCharArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < str2Array.length; i++) {

   inOfStr2Nums[i] = alphabet.indexOf(str2Array[i]);
  }
  System.out.println(inOfStr2Nums);
  return false;

 }

Answer (score -1):

To fix the error:

```
inOfStr2Nums[i] = alphabet.indexOf(str2.charAt(i));
```